# What is the largest ordinal number that is also a natural number?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, ordinals

I know that $\omega$ is the first ordinal number that is not a natural number, so I was wondering what is the largest ordinal number that is also a natural number. I was guessing $\omega-1$, but since subtraction is undefined in ordinal (and cardinal) arithmetic, I ruled it out. I am quite sure that the answer to my question is equivalent to this supremum: $$\sup(\mathrm{On}\hspace{4px}\cap\mathbb{N})$$ Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you believe this exists in the first place?

Comment: @JMoravitz I couldn't think of anything that ruled out its existence.

Comment: Suppose it did exist.  Since it is a natural number and since natural numbers can be added to one another... could you add one to it?  Would it still qualify as being "largest"?

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't see why not.

Comment: "I don't see why not" for whether you could add one to it?  Or "I don't see why not" for why it would still qualify as being "largest" even though we just showed the existence of a number larger than it?

Comment: @JMoravitz "I don't see why not" for whether you could add one to it

Comment: Okay... so you have a "largest" ordinal which is a natural number.  Call that thing $B$ (for biggest).  What kind of animal is $B+1$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I think I see the problem. Thank you for pointing it out. Does this mean that the supremum I described is equal to 0?

Comment: We would either say the supremum doesn't exist, or we would say the supremum "is infinity" which is shorthand for saying that the set is unbounded from above.  (*Do not mistake this for saying that there is actually an element named infinity who is the supremum.  Such an element need not exist*)

Comment: @JMoravitz How infinite (since we have different sized infinities)?

Comment: "**which is shorthand for saying that the set is unbounded from above**"  I already covered this.  That is why I emphasized "*is infinity*" in quotes like I had, because we do not literally mean that it *is* infinity, that is just the shorthand phrase used.

Comment: In $\mathsf{ON}$ with order $\in$ we have $\sup(\omega)=\omega$ and $\omega\notin\omega$. So $\omega$ has no largest element.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I think that $\sup(\mathrm{Ord}\cap\omega)$ *does* exist, and that set *is* bounded from above. At least if we accept that $\mathrm{Ord}\neq\omega$, or equivalently, the Axiom of Infinity.

Comment: The largest natural number ordinal? That would be [the tenth Heegner number](https://mathenchant.wordpress.com/2019/02/16/who-mourns-the-tenth-heegner-number/).

Comment: @AsafKaragila So assuming the Axiom of Infinity what would it be?

Comment: @MathGeek: $\omega$, obviously.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But $\omega$ isn't a natural number, right?

Comment: Nowhere it is claimed to be. It is simply the smallest ordinal larger than all natural numbers, i.e. $\sup(\mathrm{Ord}\cap\omega)$. And its existence is equivalent to the Axiom of Infinity.

Comment: I think it's better if you think about this question for a few seconds, rather than me giving you the answer again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since every natural number is also an ordinal number, your question reduces to

> "What is the largest natural number?"

Perhaps you already know the answer to this because, if $n$ is any candidate to be the "the largest natural number", then $n+1$ will beat it. That is, there is no such thing as the largest natural number.

You state "I am quite sure that the answer to my question is equivalent to this supremum: $\sup(\mathrm{On}\cap\mathbb N)$". The set $\mathrm{On}\cap\mathbb N$ is simply $\mathbb N$, and so $\sup(\mathrm{On}\cap\mathbb N)=\sup\mathbb N=\omega\notin\mathbb N$. The supremum of a set of ordinal numbers is not generally an element of that set. In the case when a set has a largest element, it is by definition an element of and the supremum of that set.